# Is it possible to rewrite sql clr function as sql stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, user-defined-functions, sqlclr

I use sql clr assembly in my project with sql clr user defined functions. For example:

```
[SqlFunction]
public static SqlString InsertCampaignRecipients(SqlString url) 
{
    var rowData = string.Empty;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var response = client.GetAsync(new Uri(url.Value)).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            if (result.IndexOf(@"""Exception"":null}") > 0) //success
            {
                rowData = "success";
            }
            else
            {
                rowData = string.Empty;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rowData = string.Empty;
        }
    }
    return rowData;
}
```

But I want to migrate on Azure which is not supportted by clr.
What is the solution? Is it possible to rewrite sql clr function as sql stored procedure or something?

Comment: A method that opens an http client? No, I think that would be a terrible thing to be able to do in a stored procedure.... but then, it is a terrible thing to do in a SQL CLR function, too :) This sounds like something your app-server should be doing...

Comment: Why do you have the code labeled with [SqlFunction].  The code has nothing to do with accessing the database.  The code is doing a Http Request to a server that is accessing the database.

Comment: @jdweng The OP runs the code as an SQLCLR assembly (.NET code inside SQL Server) and attributing the method with `SqlFunction` so the method is created as a SQL UDF.

Comment: Does SQL Server have a HTTP Request method?  NO!!!  So why label the method?

Comment: Is there any alternative for databases with user-defined CLR types when migrating to the Windows Azure SQL database?

Comment: @jdweng Yes, SQL Server does support the `HttpWebRequest` class via SQLCLR. Please see the series I am writing about SQLCLR on SQL Server Central: [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/).

Answer (score 1):

So you want to do an HTTP request straight from T-SQL. That is a no-can-do, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

*Currently*, Azure SQL Database does not support SQLCLR (not even for `SAFE` Assemblies). Assuming that you are using SQLCLR in the proper context of doing something that cannot be done in T-SQL, then no, there is no equivalent in Azure SQL Database. However, even if Azure SQL Database once again supports SQLCLR (it did for just over 18 months, from late 2014 through mid-April of 2016), then it still won't likely support doing external requests such as network or filesystem. Hence, the web request in the question still would not have been supported even during the time that Azure SQL Database did allow SQLCLR Assemblies.

There is a slim chance that this *might* work on the new [Azure SQL Database Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-transact-sql-information#clr), but I cannot say for certain.

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN USE C# Language Extension for SQL Server
Microsoft Open Sources .NET 5 C# Language Extension for SQL Server
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2021/09/10/csharp-sql-server.aspx

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).